# Maximizing a concave function with convex constraints.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider a convex optimization with concave objective function and convex inequality constraints, affine equality constraint. How to define the following
1. Lagrangian,
2. Lagrange dual function,
3. Upper bound property equivalent to lower bound property?

Comment: You can multiply the objective function by $-1$.

Comment: Thank you, but without changing concavity of the objective function, how can we proceed further.

Comment: Why put an artificial constraint on yourself, especially if it impedes your progress? If you are more comfortable with convex objectives, then, change the problem to an equivalent one with a convex objective. Maximizing a concave function is the same as minimizing a convex function.